# Missing 'return' statement in frontend Controller execute() method (IDE warning notice)

Tags: magento2, frontend, controllers

I recently use PhpStorm to write my code and it finds an error in a controller who get data from a `<form>` to save them in a custom model. (works fine even without correction).

```
Class StockRequestForm extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(....) 
    {
        ....
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->helper->getFormKeyValidation($this->getRequest())) {
          $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Invalid request!');
          return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
        }

        $post = (array)$this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if (!empty($post)) {
            try {
                ... // saving $model
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You\'re request have been submitted.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            }
        }
    
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();

    } // here the missing 'return' statement !
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your code. A curly braces is missing

Comment: its not really the full method, just part of it and I forgot the last one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of this phpDoc Block of your execute function

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
```

If you check the parent interface

> Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface

It clearly defines the return type

```
/**
 * Execute action based on request and return result
 *
 * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
 */
public function execute();
```

In order to fix this you should write your own or update your phpDoc Block to return void.

```
/**     
 * @return void
 */
```